# Add space for each word in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have number N *(For example 9)* and array with some words

```
array = ['quis', 'nostrud', 'exercitation', 'ullamco', 'laboris', 'nisi', 'ut', 'aliquip', 'ex', 'ea', 'commodo'];
```

For N = 9 I'd like to have next string *(add N spaces for each word from the right)*:

```
quis nostrud  exercitation  ullamco  laboris  nisi  ut  aliquip  ex  ea  commodo
```

please help me to write this on JS

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: join(" ") simply woks but you have not googled first! search working with array!!!1

Comment: @C-link `join` doesn't help with what he is asking "add N spaces for each word from the right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = ['quis', 'nostrud', 'exercitation', 'ullamco', 'laboris', 'nisi', 'ut', 'aliquip', 'ex', 'ea', 'commodo'];
var n = 9;

for (var i = arr.length - 1; i && i >= arr.length - n; i--) {
    arr[i] = ' ' + arr[i];
}

console.log(arr.join()) // quis,nostrud, exercitation, ullamco, laboris, nisi, ut, aliquip, ex, ea, commodo
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
document.write(array.join(" "));
```

Read up the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function for more information.

Comment: NO! I'd like to add space 9 times. Step by step from the right of sentence

Comment: result string: quis-nostrud--exercitation--ullamco--laboris--nisi--ut--aliquip--ex--ea--commodo

Comment: @user3226526 - you are not making sense here, show me a clear example.

Comment: if n = 9 result: "quis-nostrud--exercitation--ullamco--laboris--nisi--ut--aliquip--ex--ea--commodo" else if n = 7 result: "quis-nostrud-exercitation-ullamco--laboris--nisi--ut--aliquip--ex--ea--commodo"

Comment: Why use `document.write`? What it is that you were trying to achieve by using `document.write` in javascript example?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do that by using JavaScript native function "Join". Here is the example

```
var myarr = ['quis', 'nostrud', 'exercitation', 'ullamco', 'laboris', 'nisi', 'ut', 'aliquip', 'ex', 'ea', 'commodo'];
myarr.join(' ');
```

result: "quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo"

Comment: result string: quis-nostrud--exercitation--ullamco--laboris--nisi--ut--aliquip--ex--ea--commodo

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting it right you want this:

```
var myarr = ['quis', 'nostrud', 'exercitation', 'ullamco', 'laboris', 'nisi', 'ut', 'aliquip', 'ex', 'ea', 'commodo'];
   var rslt = "";
   var delimeter = '-';

for(var i=0;i<myarr.length-1;i++){
        rslt += myarr[i];
    for(var j=0;j<i+1;j++){
        rslt += delimeter;    
    }
}
```

reslt: quis-nostrud--exercitation---ullamco----laboris-----nisi------ut-------aliquip--------ex---------ea-----------

Comment: just change the delimeter value '-' with space ' ' to get the desired result.